# Running a XNA game in a ruby on rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xna

I was wondering if there is any way of running a 2D game built in XNA in a website built using ruby on rails. I am familiar with both languages, XNA more than ruby.

I can make a game in a fairly short amount of time, and i need to make one for a website, but i would rather use a language that i am familiar with to do this. If not is there any suggestions of languages/engines/game creating tools that i can use to build a simple 2D game that will be featured on a website?

I am a experienced in programming, i know advance programming techniques so any suggestions are fine.

Thank you

Comment: XNA isn't a language. It's a set of libraries that requires the .NET Framework to function properly. As far as I am aware, the only way to host an XNA built application in a browser is via Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is a server-side framework. XNA is a client-side framework. They don't really interoperate - nor do they need to.

You can make a 2D XNA game run in a Silverlight 3 or 4 plugin using [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/). You could also use Silverlight 5, which has a 3D API and audio API that matches XNA, and has a [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/88660) available that adds 2D XNA functionality like `SpriteBatch` and more, making the majority of the XNA API available. You then simply embed the Silverlight control in your HTML.

A regular XNA game (ie: using the official library) is an executable that would have to be downloaded from your website.